# How to hightlight Text in Solr Search using @Highlight annotation in Repository

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I have tried to highlight the text using:

```
@Highlight(prefix="<strong>",postfix="</strong>")
```

Like this:

```
@Query("articletype:?0")
@Highlight(prefix="<strong>",postfix="</strong>")
ON SOME METHOD
```

But this doesn't work.

I have even tried to highlight by passing the query as an attr in `@Highlight`. But that didn't work.

Please suggest how to use `@Highlight` with `@Query` to highlight the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

```
@Query("field_name:?0")
@Highlight(prefix="<strong>",postfix="</strong>")
public HighlightPage<YOUR_ENTITY_CLASS> yourSomeMethod(String textToBeSearched);
```

  2.

HighlightPage listSolrPage =solrRepository.yourSomeMethod(textToBeSearched);

3.

```
 for (HighlightEntry<YOUR_ENTITY_CLASS> he : listSolrPage.getHighlighted()) {
            for (Highlight highlight : he.getHighlights()) {
                    // Each highlight might have multiple occurrences within the description
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (String snipplet : highlight.getSnipplets()) {                      
                        // snipplet contains the highlighted text
                        slf4jLogger.debug(snipplet);
                        sb.append(snipplet + "");
                    }
            }
        }
```